# Local Script Downloading After CSS Files, but not External Files

Tags: javascript, css, performance, google-chrome, optimization

I've come across some interesting browser behavior (Chrome) that I was hoping to get insight into.

I have the following structure to my html document (I've been careful about the domain names)

```
 // Hosted on http://www.example.com
 <html>
    <head>
      <link href="http://cdn.com/css1.css">
      <link href="http://cdn.com/css2.css">
      <link href="http://cdn.com/css3.css">
    </head>
    <body>

      <img src="http://cdn.com/img1.jpg">
      <img src="http://cdn.com/img2.jpg">

      <script src="http://www.example.com/local-js-1.js" async></script>
      <script src="http://www.example.com/local-js-2.js" async></script>
      <script src="http://another-cdn.com/ext-js-1.js" async></script>
      <script src="http://another-cdn.com/ext-js-2.js" async></script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

But Chrome will wait until the CSS files have finished downloading before downloading the local javascript files. It (chrome) does NOT wait when those javascript files are external though. I thought it might be a number-of-resources issue, but I am not downloading ANY files from the root domain other than the index.html document and those two local javascript files.

This is true if I don't include the external javascript files or not, or if the external files are included before the local files.

Both local and external included together as described in the HTML above : 
[image: Both local and external included together as described in the HTML above]

Only Local files : Notice how the two images are requested, if I refresh the page, they will show up in a random order and the fact that they are included first here is happenstance... obviously they are all waiting for the same thing before requesting :
[image: Only Local files : Notice how the two images are requested first]

I'd prefer the local files to download concurrently with the CSS files (serving them from the same CDN as the CSS files results in the same behavior above... presumably because Chrome only downloads a few resources from the same domain at a time) so that I don't have to pay for the DNS lookup of the additional CDN so my question is "Why doesn't chrome download my locally referenced files at the same time it would download external files?"

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I wasn't able to fully reproduce your scenario... perhaps a JSbin would help. In any case, I found that ALL scripts whether same domain or other domain blocked downloading in both Chrome and Firefox. (Firefox however, has a blocking indicator on it's waterfall, so you could tell that parsing had not been blocked)

As to the answer of the question "Why does Chrome do this?". Although I can't answer that part of the question, my guess is that it's probably just a not-yet-optimized condition... apparently all the dependencies in how objects can load are difficult to untangle. For example, while looking into it, I found this 4-year old Firefox bug that's still open: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=693725

As to the more interesting question of "How do I work around it?", I find that this simple line of code gets all the CSS and script files downloading as early as possible and applied asyncronously:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  media="later"
  onload="this.onload=null;this.media='screen'"
  href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
 />
```

I checked the above in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11, and all started all downloads in parallel, and  successfully applied the CSS rules from the sheets